# I can't login to Zookeeper UI from Browser

Tags: docker, logging, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I try to login to Zookeeper UI from Browser using this credentials:
Username = admin
Password = admin
But it doesn't log in.
Zookeeper is started from Docker.

I searched the correct credentials but I don't find them.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qik4l.png)

Comment: How do you start the zookeeper? How do you start the UI? Are they both started on docker? Can you provide the commands/configuration?

Comment: I start Zookeeper UI using this command: 
sudo docker run -d --name zkui -p 9090:9090 --network tap -e ZK_SERVER=kafkaZK:2181 juris/zkui

This command for Kakfa: 
sudo docker run -e KAFKA_ACTION=start-zk --network tap --ip 10.0.100.22  -p 2181:2181 --name kafkaZK -it tap:kafka

These command for Zookeeper CLI:
sudo docker exec -it kafkaZK /bin/bash
cd /opt/kafka/bin
./zookeeper-shell.sh 10.0.100.22:2181

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default credentials: admin/manager.